# HttpResponse Error 502 on callout to internal URL

Tags: community, callout, post

Recently, I deployed a change set to my organization production environment. On production, it works fine, but on community my callout doesn't look to work as expected. Basically, on my code, I make a callout to my own organization visual force page (on a community page I make a callout to: myorgcommunity.force.com/makeRequestTrial), but it returns error 502.

Basically, this is the response from my callout:

[image: error]

**What I have tried:**

1. Given access to all used objects attributes to the user profile testing the feature
2. Given access to all used classes/test classes to the user profile testing the feature
3. Given permission set "API Enabled" to the user profile testing the feature
4. Given access to all used VFP pages (including /makeRequestTrial)
5. Given access to the url at Remote Site Settings (myorg.force.com/makeRequestTrial)

This is the code, being executed on my page callout:

```
 String postData = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('data');
    try {
        // Parse post data
        JSONParser data = JSON.createParser(postData);
        Utils utilsComponent = new Utils();
        Map<String, Object> arrData = utilsComponent.parseJsonToMap(data);

        List<Plataforma__c> listPtt = [SELECT id FROM Plataforma__c WHERE ECommerce__c =: 'a04f40000065gQc']; // Fixed id for testing
        List<Produto__c> listPt = [SELECT id FROM Produto__c WHERE Plataforma__c =: 'a04f40000065gQc']; // Fixed id for testing
        if(listPtt.size() == 0 && listPt.size() == 0) {
            pt = new Produto__c();
            pt.Nome_do_Produto__c = String.valueOf(arrData.get('Nome_do_Produto__c'));
            ptt = new Plataforma__c();
            ptt.Nome_da_Plataforma__c = String.valueOf(arrData.get('Nome_da_Plataforma__c'));
            ptt.Ecommerce__c = String.valueOf(arrData.get('eId'));
            insert ptt;
            pt.Plataforma__c = ptt.Id;
            insert pt;
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        throw new ApiException('Falha ao criar produto e plataforma.' + ex.getLineNumber());
    }
```

Also, it doesn't seem to be a code logical error since I've tried to comment the whole code block executed on my callout and still receiving an error response.

Any idea? Suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's not a valid soql: [SELECT id FROM Plataforma__c WHERE ECommerce__c =: 'a04f40000065gQc'];. Get rid of the colon

Comment: Have I understood you correctly: by "community" you mean community cloud?

Comment: Well, looks like it's a valid SOQL, since it's returning my object data at my dev/production enviroment. Also, I've tried to comment that part of the code and still returning 502 response. As "community", I mean the Salesforce communities used for partners and customers.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was talking about. Have you tried to debug, what does "postData " variable contain?

Comment: I am asking because I've never tried to use ApexPages with communities. Are you sure that's gonna work properly?

Comment: Well, I've tried but I can't debug it, since it's returning a 502 bad gateway response during my callout. This part of the code, executes when my callout is requested. As far I know, VFP works properly with communities. I've done a few tasks before (with no callouts) and they were working fine. I tried to make some research and didn't find anything about VFP's not working properly on communities. As I mentioned before, I don't think it's a code problm, because it works fine on production/dev environment and I've commented the whole callout block code. For me, I missed some config. Any idea?

Comment: Does the callback work in your sandbox?

Comment: Yes, it perfectly works on sandbox and production environment. Only at community it doesn't work.